# Can anyone show me how to eliminate Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error when using a tracking pixel?

Tags: php, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am not sure why I am getting a CORB error when trying to use a tracking pixel.
I thought that these errors do not occur if images are served back and the content type is an image (gif or jpeg). The exact error is:

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://analytics.epizy.com/pixel.php?a=5&ip=198.91.81.4&pge=/tracktester.php with MIME type text/html.

My code follows:

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    $pge =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing of Tracking Pixel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Testing of Tracking Pixel</p>
    <img src="http://analytics.epizy.com/pixel.php?a=5&ip=<?php echo $ip ?>&pge=<?php echo $pge ?>">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pixel.php follows:

```
<?php

  // Create an image, 1x1 pixel in size
  $im=imagecreate(1,1);

  // Set the background colour
  $white=imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);

  // Allocate the background colour
  imagesetpixel($im,1,1,$white);

  // Set the image type
  header("content-type:image/jpg");

  // Create a JPEG file from the image
  imagejpeg($im);

  // Free memory associated with the image
  imagedestroy($im);


    
if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
    // (Do|log) act on a
    //echo "Hope to see a value here = " . $_GET['a'];

    $servername = "sql207.epizy.com";
    $username = "epiz_22387889";
    $password = "";
    $db =  "epiz_22387889_analytics";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username, $password,$db);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testAnalyse (hitA, hitIP, hitPage, hitWhen) VALUES (?,?, ?,now())");
    $stmt->bind_param("iss", $_GET['a'], $_GET['ip'], $_GET['pge']);

    $stmt->execute();
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }

   $stmt->close();
   $conn->close();

   


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that these errors do not occur if images are served back and the content type is an image (gif or jpeg).

You're right. The problem is that your pixel gives 500 Error code:

[image]

I also tested your `pixel.php` code locally, and it throws no error. But before crashing, it writes the output image, so the client receives it.

The problem is somewhere in this piece of code

```php
if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
    // (Do|log) act on a
    //echo "Hope to see a value here = " . $_GET['a'];

    $servername = "sql207.epizy.com";
    $username = "epiz_22387889";
    $password = "";
    $db =  "epiz_22387889_analytics";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username, $password,$db);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testAnalyse (hitA, hitIP, hitPage, hitWhen) VALUES (?,?, ?,now())");
    $stmt->bind_param("iss", $_GET['a'], $_GET['ip'], $_GET['pge']);

    $stmt->execute();
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }

   $stmt->close();
   $conn->close();




}
```

And I'll be surprised if I get the wrong guess, but take a look at here:

```php
$pge =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
...
&pge=<?php echo $pge ?>
```

You don't escape `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, so anything can come up here and ruin the request. Do this instead:

```php
$ip = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
$pge = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

**UPD:** as @Martin's mentioned, there's also a problem with `bind_param`, as you set the first parameter to be `i` (integer), it has to accept the integer as well:

```php
$stmt->bind_param("iss", (int)$_GET['a'], $_GET['ip'], $_GET['pge']);
```

Comment: `GET` types are always strings;  so the Parameterised queries are failing because it's expecting an integer but getting a string; you can fix this with `$stmt->bind_param("iss", (int)$_GET['a'],`

Comment: Do you think it wasn't caused by unescaped URL?

Comment: Encoding escape is a different issue. I am refering to the issue that PHP GET values are always strings, and the bind_param is expecting an integer value.

Comment: Your last part is incorrect. It will generate an error in PHP. If you set the type to `i` then it means mysqli must cast the value to an integer, so the whole thing is actually redundant. P.S. I would highly recommend enabling mysqli error reporting instead of manually checking `$conn->error` which is a pretty bad practice.